# checking a string in bash to see if its a domain

Tags: bash, if-statement, verification

I am working on a project in Bash that takes a live xlsx file, converts it into a csv file, and checks the file to make sure that the data inside it are urls. This is part of a larger progragam that will eventually test each url for domain squatting.

I am having problems with the verification of the string data. I am having to teach myself bash as i go along since this is a self study class. Thanks for the Help!

```
INPUT=domain3.csv 
while IFS= read -r line
do
   if [[ "$line" == *".com"*] || [ "$line" == *".net"*] || [ "$line" == *".org"*] || [ "$line" == *".biz"*]];
   
   then echo "$line"

    else echo "$line is not an URL"
   fi
    echo "Finished!"
done
```

Comment: Put a valid shebang and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendations.

Comment: `I am having problems` - but what problems?

Comment: There are lots of URLs that aren't .com/.net/.org/.biz.

Comment: Your mixture of `[[` and `[` won't work. You also need spaces before `]`

Comment: this is the error i am getting
ver_loop.sh: line 8: [: missing `]'
ver_loop.sh: line 8: [: missing `]'
ver_loop.sh: line 8: [: missing `]'
ver_loop.sh: line 8: [: missing `]'
 is not an URL
Finished!

Comment: `bash`, by the way, is a terrible language for processing CSV files.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `=~` to perform regular expression match:

```sh
if [[ $INPUT =~ \.(com|net|org)$ ]]
then
    echo $INPUT is a domain
else
    echo $INPUT is not a domain
fi
```

The expression reads that if $INPUT matches a dot (\.), then one of "com", "net", or "org", then end of string ($), then it is a domain.

Answer (score 2):

`[[ ... ]]` (since `bash` 4.1) temporarily enables the `extglob` option, so you can write

```
if [[ "$line" == *.@(com|net|org|biz)* ]];
```

You probably don't actually want the trailing `*`, which would let you match things like `foo.comzzz`.

Comment: So when i try this, i get an output of 
 is not an URL                                                                                                                                       
Finished!

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Answer (score 2):

A case statement.

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r line; do
  case $line in
    *.com|*.net|*.org|*.biz)
       echo "$line";;
    *) printf >&2 '%s is not a url!\n'  "$line" ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Please execute the below code once and then compare it with your's to find out the error.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  if [[ "$line" == *".com"* ]] || [[ "$line" == *".net"* ]] || [[ "$line" == *".org"* ]] || [[ "$line" == *".biz"* ]]
  then
    echo "$line"
  else
    echo "$line is not an URL"
  fi
done < $INPUT
echo "Finished!"
```